# Xamarin.Forms Android App API Level range on Google Play Store

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

I'm trying to publish a Xamarin.Forms Android App to the Google Play Store and all is well except the API level is restricted by range. Normally apps will say API 7 and up but mine says 7.1 - 10 (see screenshots) making it "invisible" to device with Android v 11 and up. Naturally, I would like it to just say "7.1 and up"
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would close VS, delete all `bin` and `obj` folders. (windows explorer, go to root folder of solution, `search` `:=bin` and then `:=obj`). Then `Rebuild Solution` with `Release Build`. After that, please verify that the **merged** manifest, in `...\YourApp.Android\obj\Release\110\AndroidManifest.xml` says `<uses-sdk ... android:targetSdkVersion="30" />`. Though I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: If this app was previously uploaded as `.apk`, be sure to upload using `.aab` bundle format. Then at google play console / App bundle explorer, find that .aab. Confirm that it shows `Target SDK 30`. Confirm that is the same bundle that is listed as part of your current production release.

Comment: Hmm. thanks for looking into this for me. Really appreciated! Unfortunately, after removing the obj and bin from the solution (in both the Android and shared sections), cleaning the solution an project (and yes, this is .aab and it's the FIRST TIME it's submitted to the store) the issues prevails. Is there a way in Google Play to say "dude, this will work with everything 7.1 and up?"

Comment: I don't think so. Did you examine the file in `obj\release`, to see what it says there for targetSdkVersion? That's the result after merging any dependencies. I don't think that can differ from what you did in project properties, but its what google will see when uploaded. If that is correct, then describe how you are deploying. Through Azure? Appcenter? Building locally then uploading to dev console in browser? Its acting as if it isn't seeing your updated build ...

Comment: Probably not the cause, but in .Android project properties / Android Options, scroll way down to end, click "Advanced" button. `Supported architectures:` CHECK all 4 in dropdown, to make sure newer devices are supported.

Comment: One other thought: In VS, Tools / Android / Android SDK Manager, tab tools, verify that `Android SDK Platform- Tools` doesn't say there are Updates available. When I look, mine is Version 31.0.3. `Android SDK Build Tools` is 30.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

so this is really bizarre. The only way I can "force" it is by specifying a max SdkVersion in the manifest. Shouldn't have to do that (Not even recommended by Google). Perhaps will figure in the future:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="REMOVED" android:versionName="3.14" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="17">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="30" android:maxSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="REMOVED" android:icon="@drawable/splashLF" android:allowBackup="false" android:usesCleartextTraffic="false">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="org.REMOVED.REMOVED.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```